# I am trying to build a polymer site and I am wondering how to set the iron-image element at the center

Tags: css, image, polymer, alignment, polymer-2.x

Here is my code

```
<iron-image style="width:500px; height:400px; background-color: lightgray;"
    sizing="cover" preload fade src="images/1.jpg"></iron-image>
<iron-image style="width:500px; height:400px; background-color: lightgray;"
    sizing="cover" preload fade src="images/2.jpg"></iron-image>
```

This is the output of the code, I'm trying to make it on the center:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please describe the problem you encounter and include relevant code snippets.

Comment: isn't enough to wrap iron images into `div` and set `margin: 0 auto` to this div?

Comment: That was the code that I used in inserting the image. The problem is I can't move it to the center. I used align="center" tag but it cannot solve the problem since i put style inside the element. When I try to do it in css part on the <style> still not working.

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský still not working here is the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/usfbi54hkw6rpub/1.PNG?dl=0&m=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use iron-flex-layout**

```
<custom-style>
  <style is="custom-style">
    .flex-center-justified {
      @apply --layout-horizontal;
      @apply --layout-center-justified;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>

<div class="container flex-center-justified">
  <iron-image style="width:500px; height:400px; background-color: lightgray;"
    sizing="cover" preload fade src="images/1.jpg"></iron-image>
  <iron-image style="width:500px; height:400px; background-color: lightgray;"
    sizing="cover" preload fade src="images/2.jpg"></iron-image>
</div>
```